# How to customise fluentd config when using the kubernetes fluentd-elasticsearch addon

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

We'd like to customise the fluentd config that comes out of the box with the kubernetes fluentd-elasticsearch addon.  It seems however that there is no easy way of doing this with the current supplied Docker images.

The following file: [td-agent.conf](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-image/td-agent.conf) is copied to the fluentd-es Docker image with no (apparent) way of us being able to customise it.

We need to customise this config file so that we can handle multi-line log entries as one event.  Most likely this would invovle making use of the multiline format (as detailed here [fluentd in_tail](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail)) which would obviously mean a change from the default config file.

Currently a multi line Java stack trace appears in Kibana as multiple entires which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any method to customize the config. You can either create your own image, open a feature request at [issues.k8s.io](http://issues.k8s.io), or even submit a PR to to enhance fluentd.

Answer (score 0):

You can still have a look at [this guy](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8fd414537b5143ab039cb910590237cabf4af783/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-image), edit the `td-agent.conf` and build your own fluentd-elasticsearch image :)